# Android webview not filling device screen height

Tags: android, webview

I am using a webview to load html data.

I want to place two buttons on the bottom for some functionality.

I have put teh webview and the bottom layout in a frame layout.

Web view shows html data only when i give it some specific height  e.g 500dp.

Also the bottom layout also scrolls along with webview.

Please help how i can do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newsHeading"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Heading"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewNews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/back1"
            android:padding="20dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/share11"
            android:padding="20dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: share the layout code

Comment: Take separate layout for showing webview.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I have fixed it by changing the LinearLayout by a RelativeLayout and setting all the "parent aligments" to the WebView, but this fill the screen.

For your layout, try align your button's LinearLayout to the parent's bottom, and replace the alignParentBottom of the WebView by a layout_above anchored to it. I have tested it and works fine.

Here is the code, try it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linlyt_buttons"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlyt_buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rellyt_imagebuttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="Back/Cancel"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="Share"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button2"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```